# How to use variables throughout a web application in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, webforms

I have been tasked to create a calculator on a C# web application, however I noticed that when I use variables set in other buttons, the programs sets them to 0, specifically the 'num' and 'sign' variable which I assigned in the PlusBut but when actually using them in the EqualBut they are assigned to 0. My code works in a windows form but this is my first time using website application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1 {
    public partial class About: System.Web.UI.Page {
        int sign;
        double num, num2;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        protected void But0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            AnswerBox.Text = AnswerBox.Text + "0";
        }

        protected void But1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            AnswerBox.Text = AnswerBox.Text + "1";
        }

        protected void But2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            AnswerBox.Text = AnswerBox.Text + "2";
        }

        protected void But3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            AnswerBox.Text = AnswerBox.Text + "3";
        }

        protected void But4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            AnswerBox.Text = AnswerBox.Text + "4";
        }

        protected void But5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            AnswerBox.Text = AnswerBox.Text + "5";
        }

        protected void But6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            AnswerBox.Text = AnswerBox.Text + "6";
        }

        protected void But7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            AnswerBox.Text = AnswerBox.Text + "7";
        }

        protected void But8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            AnswerBox.Text = AnswerBox.Text + "8";
        }

        protected void But9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            AnswerBox.Text = AnswerBox.Text + "9";
        }

        protected void PlusBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            num = double.Parse(AnswerBox.Text);
            AnswerBox.Text = "";
            sign = 1;

        }

        protected void DecBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            AnswerBox.Text = AnswerBox.Text + ".";
        }

        protected void MinusBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            num = double.Parse(AnswerBox.Text);
            AnswerBox.Text = "";
            sign = 2;
        }

        protected void MultBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            num = double.Parse(AnswerBox.Text);
            AnswerBox.Text = "";
            sign = 3;
        }

        protected void DivButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            num = double.Parse(AnswerBox.Text);
            AnswerBox.Text = "";
            sign = 4;
        }

        protected void EqualBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            num2 = double.Parse(AnswerBox.Text);
            AnswerBox.Text = "" + num + " " + num2 + " " + sign;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also sorry for poor pasting at start of the code however the start is irrelevant

Answer (score 2):

Essentially when you trigger a postback (by clicking a button in your case), a new instance of the `About` class is created and the previous values of your fields are lost.

You should read about [ASP Page Life Cycle Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

There are multiple approaches to making variables persistent, one is to use `Session` or `ViewState` variables, which is probably the simplest solution in your case and should be sufficient for a calculator.

```
double num1
{
    get { return Convert.ToDouble(ViewState["num1"] ?? 0); }
    set { ViewState["num1"] = value; }
}
```

Another approach would be to use JavaScript to avoid postbacks, however that would increase the complexity of your app by combining client side and server side actions.

Comment: ViewState should be enabled by default. @SeanBUTCHER In the `Page` element in your .aspx file, are you setting `EnableViewState` to `false`?

Comment: @GabrielLuci True, ViewState should be preferred unless OP requires access to the variable across multiple pages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a bit, but I think your problem is that web applications don't persist from one button press to another. Every time the user presses a button, the browser sends a request to the server. The server creates the web application and gives it the request, and the application produces the result.

You need to persist values from one request to the next. There are several ways to do this, but it's normal to save them to a session. The exact implantation depends on what web technology you're using.

Comment: Looks like ASP.NET Web Forms. But you're exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is server side. So each time a click is triggered at client side a new instance of About is created and sign, num and num2 are created with default value (aka 0).

Either change to a client side programming language as JavaScript or define the values as static. Static variables are linked to the class and not an instance of it, so they will hold the value between callbacks:

```
public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static int sign;
    static double num;
    static double num2;
    /* ... */
    protected void PlusBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        About.num = double.Parse(AnswerBox.Text);
        AnswerBox.Text = "";
        sign = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would only work if one person is using the application at a time. If two people use it at the same time, it would produce some..... interesting math.